# Use scipy.stats.rv_histogram() function to sample from 2d histogram

Tags: python, scipy

The scipy's function [rv_histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_histogram.html) is quite useful if I have an empirical distribution that is given by a histogram that I want to sample from. So I can sample new data as shown in this minimal example:

```
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

x = np.array(range(2,8))
hist_1d = pd.DataFrame(np.array([11., 46., 158., 75., 90., 14.]), index=x)
plt.plot(x + 0.5, hist_1d.values)
dist = scipy.stats.rv_histogram((hist_1d.values.ravel(), np.array(range(2,9))))
plt.hist(dist.rvs(size=500), bins=len(x))
```

[image: 1D Histogram]

Now I want to do the same for a 2D distribution given in this minimal example:

```
hist_2d = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[129, 162, 178, 182, 182, 182],
                   [122, 163, 185, 191, 189, 185],
                   [115, 164, 192, 200, 197, 189],
                   [ 94, 136, 158, 162, 157, 152],
                   [ 74, 108, 124, 125, 118, 116],
                   [ 53,  80,  90,  88,  79,  80]]),
                  index=range(2,8), columns=range(8,14))
sns.heatmap(hist_2d)
```

[image]

However, the [rv_histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_histogram.html) function sees to only take 1D data - or at least I don't know how to pass two vectors of bin boundaries. Is this possible, or is there a similar function in Python?

## Edit: A possible solution

I accepted the answer below, as it answers the question as phrased that it is not possible using the function and I didn't find simiar functions in the Scipy/Python datascience stack.

Just for future reference a possible solution I found based on [this](https://gist.github.com/ntamas/1109133/30362d4a91cfadc5ab69c23c63705b919a31c8a9) implementation of Walker Sampling:

```
from walker import WalkerRandomSampling

keys = list(itertools.product(hist_2d.index, hist_2d.columns))
values = hist_2d.values.flatten()

wrand = WalkerRandomSampling(weights=values, keys=keys)
samples = wrand.random(100000)

hist,_,_ = np.histogram2d(x= samples[:,0], y=samples[:,1], bins=6)
sns.heatmap(hist)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the whole `rv_generic` hierarchy is 1D only, and it includes `rv_histogram`.

Comment: Mh. Okay, was afraid that is the case. So this answers the "Is this possible" part of my question. Are you aware of a similar function for the 2D case in the Python universe?

Comment: No, I'm not, and I guess I'd DIY if I need one. Xan ask a separate questipn though.

Comment: I accept the answer as it answers the question as it is. Just for reference, I added the solution I now used in the question. Thanks!